# How to set up Ubuntu Server as a NAS?

Tags: server, nas

I am looking to set up Ubuntu Server as a headless NAS for my home. I would like to have file storage there, as well as a central hub for my MP3s and pictures.

What are the best packages out there to handle this? Can someone post a link to a good tutorial or post some tips?

One constraint I have is that it has to be Windows 7 friendly. By that I mean the shares and streaming should work for a Windows machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just finished doing this myself and I did it using Samba.  I'm able to mount the samba shares from my windows & ubuntu computers

Here are some links that helped me get started:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=280473

Comment: This is why a link farm is not considered an answer. The first link gets redirected to a generic Samba page. The original must have been removed.

Answer (score 10):

Simples:

1. Install Ubuntu Server. Really helps if you can have the server with a keyboard and monitor for this bit... Although you *can* script a CD to auto-install if you want. More trouble than it's worth if you ask me.
2. Create a user, set up ssh (`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`), etc. Put your server in its final resting place and ssh in from your desktop.
3. [Install & configure samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba) (see the manual configuration section)
4. Optionally [install NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) for linux clients (faster, less taxing on the server CPU in my experience)
5. Relax. You're done.

Answer (score 5):

For the filesystem, I have software RAID 5 across my drives, and encrypt the resulting filesystem.  This way, I can use this system as a backup server as well.

Once the system is up, I use plain ol' NFS and Samba for the file level access.  (apt-get install nfs-kernel-server samba).  I also have a PS3 that I like to stream media to, so I use mediatomb for that (apt-get install mediatomb), and my wife uses iTunes on her Mac and netbook, so I also install mt-daapd (apt-get install mt-daapd) to share my music over the daap protocol, which rhythmbox can also use.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the Ubuntu based [TurnKey File Server appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/fileserver). If you don't need a full-fledged appliance, you could use it as a reference for configuration on your own server.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this so I can find it in the future.
Install Ubuntu Cloud VM (add an extra disk 1TB or larger.)

Note:  you should replace `username` with your user.

Mount and Format the disk:

```
lsblk
sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
n
p
Enter defaults for rest of options
```

Make the filesystem

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

Make a mount path:

```
mkdir /home/username/data
```

Update Fstab

```
sudo echo "/dev/sdc1 /home/username/data ext4 defaults 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
```

Install the tools you need:

```
sudo apt install vim screen htop sysstat curl wget
sudo apt install nfs-server samba
```

Update Exports for NFS (I'm setting this based on subnet, you can change as needed)

```
sudo echo "/home/username/data 192.168.1.0/24(rw,no_root_squash)" >> /etc/exports
sudo exportfs -a
```

Make Cifs share:

```
sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
shift+g
o
```

Paste the following

```
[data]
comment = Data
browseable = yes
path = /home/username/data
guest ok = no
read only = no
create mask = 0700
```

Generate smbpasswd (this will allow windows hosts to connect over smb, granted we are passing them in with the `username` account (smile))

```
sudo smbpasswd -a username
```

Update permissions if needed:

```
sudo chown -R username:root /home/username/data
```

Download some data (this is a good dump of isos)

```
cd /home/username/data
wget -H -r --level=5 --restrict-file-names=windows --convert-links -e robots=off --no-check-certificate https://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wnat DLNA support, then see: [MiniDLNA - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I made a Ubuntu based NAS with file sharing based on **Samba** and **Nextcloud** and works across Windows, Linux or Mac. I haven't yet setup a "real" streaming server (e.g. Plex), but I use Nextcloud which is something like a Google Drive clone, which allows easy viewing of photos, music and videos through web browser.

**My Ubuntu NAS:**

- Intel NUC PC
- Ubuntu Server 20.04 (headless)
- External RAID1 USB3 drive QNAP TR-002 (this whole drive is shared, LUKS encrypted ext4 partition)
- Samba (for LAN file-share access)
- Nextcloud (optional, for cloud access)
- UFW firewall (optional)
- iDrive (optional as cloud backup of all drives including RAID USB3)

**Samba Setup:**

First I mostly followed this [guide to set up Samba](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-samba-server-share-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) users.

I edit the samba config (`sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`) and make 2 changes:

1. Under `[global]` section I added `inherit permissions = yes` to make sure permissions for added files are correct.
2. Configure my shared folder by adding to the bottom as follows:

```
[mynas]
  comment = The Big USB drive
  path = /media/usb0/
  read only = no
  browsable = yes
  writable = yes
  create mask = 0640
  directory mask = 0750
  valid users = vijay
  hide files = /$RECYCLE.BIN/System Volume Information/thumbs.db/
```

Remember to restart Samba after changes:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

And if your server has a firewall, remember to allow it:

```
sudo ufw allow samba
```

Access on Linux: `smb://192.168.1.2/mynas/`

Access on Windows File Explorer: `\\192.168.1.2\mynas\`

In my case I need to log in as "vijay" to access the shares, but the password can be saved on the client so it is only entered on first access.

**Nextcloud Setup:**

I used the [Snap package](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap) which is probably easiest. I usually avoid Snap but in this case it worked well.  You can also try [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/) or [manually](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/19/admin_manual/installation/) set everything up if you are an advanced user.

For Snap version, I just ran the following after installation to allow access to USB drive and ports:

```
sudo snap set nextcloud ports.http=81 ports.https=444
sudo snap connect nextcloud:removable-media
```

I then set up a reverse proxy (Haproxy) and SSL for secure external access over the web, but that is beyond the scope of this short guide.