# Which version of Ubuntu is best for home media server and NAS?

Tags: mediaserver

I have an HP microserver with 2GB ram and AMD N40L processor. I want to know what Ubuntu version will be best for and home media centre and also NAS?

Answer (score 2):

On of the steps below is to install Ubuntu.  You can download [Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server).  It is supported for five years, and installation is simple and straight forwrd.

> How to build a Linux media server
>
> If you've ever fancied the idea of building a server to store your
>   ever-growing collection of media files, be it movies, photos or music,
>   but have been put off doing so because it seems far too complicated to
>   build one yourself, or you've simply no idea how to go about doing it,
>   then read on. This step-by-step guide will show you how to build and
>   configure a media server that is far more powerful and far more
>   flexible than any of the "pre-built" systems on the market today. Not
>   only that but it's cheaper too!
>
> So, how do I build this Ubuntu media server then?
>
> Talking about what this media server must be able to do is one thing
>   but you want to know how to actually build it, right? Of course you
>   do. So then, without further ado, here are my 5 steps to happiness:
>
> 1. Choose the components
> 2. Assemble the components
> 3. Install Ubuntu
> 4. Configure the server
> 5. Install software applications <sup>1</sup>

For more information [Read On](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source: [Have the know how](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server is the best version and depending on how you want to consume your media you could try xmbc which is an easy download

http://www.noobslab.com/2011/09/install-xbmc-on-ubuntu-1110-oneiric.html

The NAS questions has been asked a lot though [How to set up Ubuntu Server as a NAS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-server-as-a-nas)